# Wierd micro displacement

Tags: materials, uv, modifiers

I have a strange behavior as I am trying to setup micro displacement. I use blender 2.79b. My mesh have a Subsuf modifier from the experimental feature set with the adaptative option turned on, the displacement settings in the material is set to true.

[image: ugly preview render]

This is a part of the shamefull result. These black stripes follow the seams I used to unwrap the UVs. On top of that the micro displacement does not show up. 
Do you know can cause this ?

Ps : Tell me if you need more details.

This is the material nodes setup I'm using. No displace modifier involved.

[image: material nodes setup]

Making a normal render did not fixed the issue. The object has rougthly 100k+ vertices accross 150 blender units in x and y. (subsurf modifier unapplied)

Comment: Are you using the displacement modifier or displacement through material nodes?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a displacement node (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> vector/displacement) to your texture and plug it to height socket.
[image: displacement]

Answer (score 0):

Can we have some more info about the scene/object?
Also, the apparent lack of adaptive subdiv may just be due to the low resolution of it in the viewport (by default about 8x less detail, I believe). Try rendering the image normally.